# ArrayList Issue Java, Blank Array Second time in loop

Tags: java

The following loop will run correctly once, but the second time the arraylist will simply print as []. Since its empty, when I call the getAverage method, i get a divide by zero method.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < amount_of_names*2 ; j++) {
        System.out.println(j+"J");
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // get arraylist of next series
        scores = readNextSeries(Scannerb);
        System.out.println(scores+"here");
        scores.remove(scores.size()-1);
        // get mean
        int average = getAverage(scores);
        System.out.println(average + "is" + scores);
        // put arraylist of next series in total arraylist
        combiner(scores);
        //remove all elements in temp scores array
        scores.clear();
        System.out.println(scores);
    }


the output is: Enter a read file: input.txt
5
0J
[88, 92, 78]readnextseries
[88, 92, 78]here
86is[88, 92, 78]
[]
1J
[]readnextseries
[]here
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

getAverage code:

```
private static int getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> inList) {
    int total = 0;
    // sum all arraylist elemtents
    for (int score : inList) {
        total += score;
    }
    // average is total/number of scores
    int average = total / inList.size();
    return average;
}
```

GET SERIES CODE:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> readNextSeries(Scanner Scannerb) {
    ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // store player name in names ArrayList
    names.add(Scannerb.nextLine());
    // repeat this process until -1 is read
    while (Scannerb.hasNextInt()) {
        // grab next Integer
        int test = Scannerb.nextInt();
        // if Integer is positive
        if (test > 0) {
            // add integer to score arrayList
            score.add(test);
            // if Integer is negative
        } else if (test == -1) {
            // add a -1 to the arrayList; Marks each Player's scores
            score.add(-1);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("SomethingWenTWrong");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(score+"readnextseries");
    return score;
}
```

pastebin: http://pastebin.com/qhGr3JCr

Comment: Where is your division for which the denominator is zero?

Comment: Please post your ``getAverage()`` code.

Comment: Your code for ``readNextSeries()`` might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the exception at runtime just check before divide like this -

```
if(d != 0){
   int result = someNumber/d;
}
```

Comment: right but im confused why the arrray is empty the second time

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it seems like the method readNextSeries(Scannerb)  returns an empty array in the second round. Indeed, the subsequently call to System.out.println prints and empty array.
You should post the other part of the code for further investigation.

Comment: i'll pastebin the whole thing

Comment: Ok, I guess that the problem is in the  while condition of the readNextSeries method...maybe there's an error in the second line of the input.

Comment: but the String line is stored as a String so is nextInt() wrong?

Comment: check if the line represents an integer. If not, use next()